# Log file not being created in linux/EC2 instance

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services, logging, logback

Hi I have created logback.xml the log files are not created when I am deploying the app in the ec2 server.

I tested in windows/eclipse and it creates the log file in windows path. But it is not created in linux/EC2 machine.

Below is my logback.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<property name="DEV_HOME" value="/home/ec2-user/logs" />

<appender name="FILE-AUDIT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <!-- class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender"> -->
    <file>${DEV_HOME}/debug.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>

<logger name="com.technomedha.subscribe" level="DEBUG"
    additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
</logger>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
</root>

</configuration>
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the path of value="/home/ec2-user/logs"  to value = "/tmp/logs" since the /tmp folder has rwx permissions in the linux box.

After changing the path it worked for me perfectly and the logs are stored in the folder.

Comment: HI Which log4j dependencies did u use. And How to add log your java class